# Meaning of "and so"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> His mother does not like him to go to town by himself but that’s where
> all the roads lead. **And so**.

I saw this from *The Intuitionist* by Colson Whitehead. I looked up the dictionary for "and so" but still can't figure out what does it mean when it is used independently. I mean when it is not in a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases the "And so" would be followed by ellipses to indicate that something happened after that first sentence. The first sentence states his mother's restriction and the reward of violating that restriction. The author relies on the reader's instincts about human nature: the son will go. By not using conventional ellipses, the author says the son's actions are certain. Of course the author knows the construction is violating grammar and punctuation rules, but this is a compact and powerful way to make his point about the event.

Comment: This is a good explanation of the use of *and so* in this case, but, to avoid misleading the future visitors to this page, it should be emphasised that such creative use of constructions that violate the ordinary rules can produce the intended literary effects only in the hands of very skillful writers. In other words, this is not an example to be emulated, unless one really, really knows what one is doing.

Answer (score -3):

Proposition or conjunction

> And so our intrepid explorer went to the....

> ...and so, as time went on the

Modifier that implies that the sentence following it, is the natural consequence of the sentence of which precedes it.

Cause and effect.

Comment: Hello Juan. OP is asking about the unusual standalone usage: there _is_ no following sentence to read.